# Replace HTML span + style tag to HTML 4 font tag

Tags: java, html

What is the fastest way to replace Html5 span style tags:

```
<html>
<body>

<p>
   This is My text and <span style = "color:red; font-weight:bold">this is some text</span> even more
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

to HTML4 font tag:

```
<html>
<body>

<p>
   This is My text and <font color="red">this is some text</font> even more
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

ignoring all style properties, leaving only `color`.

Comment: Were you planning on using Java to modify the files?  Is this a one-time thing?

Comment: No, just strings. Use case: Component returns me HTML5 while I need to have HTML4.

Comment: You know that [<font> is deprecated](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#h-15.2.2) and `<span style=...` is the correct way to write HTML, right?

Comment: I know. but in my case it is rather custom format for text.